# pandas read excel same columns merge

Tags: python, pandas

```
excel = pandas.read_excel(file, ...)
columns = df.columns
print(columns)

["AA", "AA.1", "AA.2"]
```

this is same names

how do you names merge?

i want ["AA"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say merge, do you want sum? Use `groupby` with `axis=1` and use string manipulation on columns names:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum()
```